# Jquery how to create a slider ? Input field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to create a slider for a input field with Jquery?

Like there is on this page: http://www.whoishostingthis.com/compare/
With the price and diskspace

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery UI
take a look at:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#steps

Comment: How to create the unlimited method? Like if the price is 9999 it is unlimited ?

Comment: there is no such thing as unlimited(infinity) in computers science. You should define maximum value. So yes - let's say it is 9999, you can define it as unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

As Kestutis said, you could use jQuery UI Slider. It provides a `slide` event, which is called as the slider is *slid*. In the function, you can access the handle element with `ui.handle`. You could put in whatever text on the handle at each increment.

For example, the following snippet will display the slider value as it is slid, and display the text "unlimited" when it reaches the maximum value.

```
$("#slider").slider({
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.value == $(this).slider('option', 'max'))
            $(ui.handle).html('unlimited');
        else
            $(ui.handle).html(ui.value);
    }
});
```

You would also need to modify the css style for the handle a little bit:

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle
{
    width: auto;
    padding: 0.2em;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/TbAQd/.

---

**Update**

You can use the `.slider('value', [value])` function to set the value of the slider. You may also want to handle the `change` event, so when the value changes, the handle would be updated as well.

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/TbAQd/1/.

---

**Update 2**

http://jsfiddle.net/william/TbAQd/3/

Comment: How do I get the slider to set a value for a input field?

Comment: I mean just the opposite, the slider should update the input field :) I would then just use simply css to hide the input field.